# Можно ли найти по значению атрибуту не перебирая массив?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть json, в нем ключи и текст.
Как разобрать его на `jQuery`?
Разбираю таким образом, но не совпадают `$(this).attr('menu')` и `data.key[i]`. 
В `jQuery` можно ли найти по значению атрибуту?

```
$(".acc_menu_main .dropdown-menu-new .popover-new").each(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('menu') + ' ' + data.key[i]);

    if ($(this).attr('menu') == "id" + data.key[i]){

    $(".popover-new[menu=" + $(this).attr('menu') + "]").html(data.text[i]);
    }
    else if ($(this).attr('menu') == "brand"){
    $(".popover-new[menu=" + $(this).attr('menu') + "]").html(data.brand);
    }
    i++;
});
```

JSON:

```
{"key":["937","588","589"],"text":["bla","bla2","bla3"]}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="popover-new" menu="{$item2->id}"></div>
```

Comment: приведи в вопросе json и разметку html.... не совсем понятно, что значит  `разобрать его на jquery`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский вставить текст в определенный аттрибут

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Да, искать по значениям атрибутов можно. Достаточно открыть документацию ..

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

.. и немного её почитать. После текста будет блок ссылок на разные вариации фильтров. Выбирайте на свой вкус!

Comment: Очень помогли! Благодарю. :)

Comment: @Irina Kochenova, Помогло - щелкните галочку ;)

Comment: Ответы-ссылки не приветствуются сообществом. Пожалуйста, исправьте ответ, перенеся ключевые тезисы в тело ответа.